# Why ScrollView's scroll not working (when RecycleView inside with disabled scroll)

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I cant understand what I am doing wrong. I had a `ScrollView` and `RecyclerView` inside it. I know that double scroll is disabled in Android. I disabled scroll on `RecyclerView` dynamically. And after it ScrollView's scroll must work. But its not.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView lvParents;
ParentsAdapter adapter_parents;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lvParents = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.lvParents);
    fillListParents();
}

public void fillListParents(){
    ArrayList listParents = new ArrayList();
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            ParentsAdapterObject parObj = new ParentsAdapterObject(
                    "pinfo_id",
                    "pinfo_title",
                    "pinfo_date",
                    "pinfo_text");
            listParents.add(parObj);
            Log.d("rklogs", "j_" + j);
    }
    adapter_parents = new ParentsAdapter(listParents, this);
   LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean canScrollVertically() {
            return false;
        }
    };
    lvParents.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    lvParents.setAdapter(adapter_parents);
}
```

**ParentsAdapter**

```
public class ParentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ParentsAdapter.PersonViewHolder>{
public static Context ctx;
ParentsAdapterObject pd;
ArrayList<ParentsAdapterObject> listParents;
public ParentsAdapter(ArrayList<ParentsAdapterObject> listParents, Context ctx){
    this.listParents = listParents;
    this.ctx= ctx;
}

@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_parents_adapter,
            viewGroup, false);
    PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
    pd = listParents.get(i);
    personViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(pd.getTitle());
    personViewHolder.pdo = pd;
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listParents.size();
}
@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTitle;
    ParentsAdapterObject pdo;
    PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("rklogs", tvTitle.getText().toString());
                Log.d("rklogs", pdo.getTitle());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

**ParentsAdapterObject**

```
public class ParentsAdapterObject {

public String title;
public String text;
public String date;
public String id;
public ParentsAdapterObject(String id, String title, String date, String text){
    this.title = title;
    this.date = date;
    this.text = text;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}
public String getText(){
    return text;
}
public String getId(){
    return id;
}
public String getDate(){
    return date;
}
```

}

**main_activity**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="row.balinasoft.by.testfucknigscroll.MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:background="#251100ff"
    android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lvParents"

            android:visibility="visible"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ScrollView`  use   `NestedScrollView`

and `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` on `RecyclerView` object

`NestedScrollView`  has ability to handle (enable/disable) inner scrolling

Comment: Thanks for your answer, N J. But it doest help me :(

Answer (score 0):

After you disable scrolling on the recycler view object as you mentioned, you could check the below snippet which uses a nested scroll view rather than a normal scroll view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <!-- your other view's/view-group's go here-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, niranjian_b. But it doest help me :(